# How to emphasize parts of title when italic

Tags: formatting, titles, titlesec

In a book project of mine, journal titles always have to be in italics, also in titles, also in the TOC.

But what to do if the style dictates that some titles shall be italic in themselves?

What I want: in titles with italic formatting (here: the section) the emphasized part of it shall be in normal font, not italic.

What I get: all the section title is in italic.

I have tried to replace \textit with \normalfont in the section title, but that also removes the desired italicization in the TOC - and it does not only set the part between the brackets, but all the rest of the title in normalfont.

How can I achieve that the \textit command in an italic environment reverts the italicization? If that is impossible, is there another command to manually set the format for part of a title?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\makeatletter%hier definition schriftgrößen-makro
  \newcommand\chapsize{\@setfontsize\chapsize{13pt}{6}}
  \newcommand\secsize{\@setfontsize\secsize{11.5pt}{6}}
  \newcommand\pnsize{\@setfontsize\pnsize{10.5pt}{6}}
  \newcommand\appsize{\@setfontsize\appsize{9pt}{6}}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
   {\chapsize\centering}{\thechapter.\ }{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang] 
    {\secsize\centering}{\thesection\ }{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang] 
    {\pnsize\centering\itshape}{\thesubsection\ }{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang] 
    {\centering}{\thesubsubsection\ }{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont \itshape}{\theparagraph.}{.7em}{}[.]%Paragraph kursiv mit Punkt
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{8mm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{4.233mm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{18pt}{6pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begingroup
  \makeatletter \let\ps@plain\ps@empty \makeatother
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1 with a \textit{Journal title} in it}
\textit{Journal titles} should always be emphasized, also in titles and the TOC.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure of what you really want, but perhaps @StevenB.Segletes 's  answer does not address exactly your aim. In principle, `\emph` by itself toggles the font between normal and italic depending of the surrounding font, in order to keep the emphasis.This means that you neither need to use explicit `\textit` nor to redefine `\emph`.

Comment: Thank you both - I was not aware that \emph was doing exactly what I wanted: emphasizing relative to the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way it is often done is to use `\emph` (emphasize) rather than `\textit`. In this way, `\emph` can be defined as `\textit` most of the time, but be defined as something else when the governing style is italic. Try `\subsection{Subsection 1.1 with a \emph{Journal title} in it}` in your example and see:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\makeatletter%hier definition schriftgrößen-makro
  \newcommand\chapsize{\@setfontsize\chapsize{13pt}{6}}
  \newcommand\secsize{\@setfontsize\secsize{11.5pt}{6}}
  \newcommand\pnsize{\@setfontsize\pnsize{10.5pt}{6}}
  \newcommand\appsize{\@setfontsize\appsize{9pt}{6}}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
   {\chapsize\centering}{\thechapter.\ }{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang] 
    {\secsize\centering}{\thesection\ }{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang] 
    {\pnsize\centering\itshape}{\thesubsection\ }{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang] 
    {\centering}{\thesubsubsection\ }{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont \itshape}{\theparagraph.}{.7em}{}[.]%Paragraph kursiv mit Punkt
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{8mm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{4.233mm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{18pt}{6pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begingroup
  \makeatletter \let\ps@plain\ps@empty \makeatother
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1 with a \emph{Journal title} in it}
\textit{Journal titles} should always be emphasized, also in titles and the TOC.
\end{document}
```

`\emph` shows as italic in toc:

[image]

`\emph` shows as roman inside of italic heading:

[image]